# The <Provider> component does not pass the store and the page is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, provider

The  component does not pass the store into 'connect()()' and the page is not rendered.

code in the file index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import store from './redux/storeRedux.js';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

let rerenderEntireTree = () => {
      root.render(
            <React.StrictMode>
                  <Provider store={store} > 
                        <App />
                  </Provider>
            </React.StrictMode>
      );
}

rerenderEntireTree(store.getState());

store.subscribe(rerenderEntireTree);
```

code in component :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Dialogs from './components/Dialogs/Dialogs';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer.jsx';
import Header from './components/Header/Header.jsx';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile.jsx';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar/SideBar.jsx';
import News from './components/News/News.jsx';
import Music from './components/Music/Music.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Settings from './components/Settings/Settings.jsx';

const App = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Header />
        <SideBar  />
        <div className="app-wrapper-content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile  />} />
            <Route path='/dialogs/*' element={<Dialogs  />} />
            <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
            <Route path='/music' element={<Music />} />
            <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


export default App;
```

code in component :

```
import React from 'react';
import MyPostsContainer from './MyPosts/MyPostsContainer';
import classes from './Profile.module.css'
import ProfileInfo from './ProfileInfo/ProfileInfo';

const Profile = (props) => {

      return (
            <main className={classes.mainBlock}>
                  <ProfileInfo />
                  <MyPostsContainer  />
            </main>
      )
}

export default Profile;
```

Code in component :

```
import React from 'react'; //My vsCode output massage -- Never use. Some body know why ?
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addPostActionCreator, updateNewPostTextActionCreator } from '../../../redux/ProfileReducer';
import MyPosts from './MyPosts';


let mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
            posts: state.profilePage.postsData,
            newPostText: state.profilePage.newPostText,
      }
};

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

      return {
            updateNewPostText: (text) => {
                  dispatch(updateNewPostTextActionCreator(text))
            },
            addPost: () => {
                  dispatch(addPostActionCreator())
            },
      }
};

const MyPostsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPosts);

export default MyPostsContainer;
```

In docementation  React-Redux  i read that problem could be in ESlint but it is not ((
Maybe it is foolish quation but i learning React and React-Redax and wanna understant how to use it.
Thanks for all who will hepl.
#React #Redux #React-Redux #Provider #Component #connect

I wanna use  from React-Redux  and send my store into my conteiner component MyPostsContainer used 'connect()()'.

Output: My SPA is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused on a couple parts.

First, it's not clear what actual error you're seeing.  When you say "the SPA is not rendering", do you mean that *nothing* shows up on screen at all?

Next, a couple pieces of the setup code look wrong:

```
rerenderEntireTree(store.getState());

store.subscribe(rerenderEntireTree);
```

As written, your `rerenderEntireTree` function does *not* need `store.getState()` passed in, so you can remove that.  You also don't need to call `store.subscribe()` at all.  React-Redux will do that for you.

That said, this *looks* like it ought to run overall.

Also, while it's not a direct answer to your question, you should know that this is a *very* outdated approach to writing Redux code. With "modern Redux", we use the React-Redux hooks API (`useSelector`/`useDispatch`), and do *not* use `connect()` or "container components". I'd recommend going through our Redux docs tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure .

**update**

Unfortunately your app setup is now *very* wrong :(  Looking at the repo link you provided, you have:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

let rerenderEntireTree = (state) => {

      root.render(
            <React.StrictMode>
                  <App state={store.getState()}
                        dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)}
                        // publicMassage={store.publicMassage.bind(store)}
                        // updateNewMassageText={store.updateNewMassageText.bind(store) }
                  />
            </React.StrictMode>
      );
}

rerenderEntireTree(store.getState());

store.subscribe(rerenderEntireTree);
```

That is *not* how you're supposed to use React-Redux, at all:

- You should *not* pass `store.getState()` to the rest of the app code
- You should *not* pass `store.dispatch` down yourself
- You should *not* call `store.subscribe()` manually

**React-Redux will do all that for you**.

You also do *not* need a `rerenderEntireApp` function, either.

Your first example was closer.  You need to wrap your `<App>` component in `<Provider store={store}.`.

A correct setup would be:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode
)
```

and then you should use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks in your components.

Unfortunately you seem to be following some *very* outdated and incorrect tutorials.

***Please* go through our official Redux docs tutorials - they'll show you the correct way to use Redux and React-Redux**:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I left only rerenderEntireTree(), but nothing changed.

If you have time or inspiration to find out why exactly it does not work, I will leave a link to the repository: https://github.com/1dlz-envio/first_react_app

In any case, I am grateful for the comment and advice on using modern methods of working with Redax

Comment: @IgorSalm updated my answer. Please go through the official Redux tutorials that I linked!